# angular 4 unit test: Cannot read property 'injector' of null

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have to following test (using karma and jasmine)
note that I call `initTestEnvironment` elsewhere, but I verified it gets called (with a console.log).

Whenever I run it I get:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'injector' of null`

As you can see `MyService` is just an empty class to demonstrate that the error above happens with every service I tried to inject.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

}

describe('some tests', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                HttpModule,
                HttpClientModule
            ],
            providers: [

                MyService
            ]
        });
    });

    it('just a test', () => {

        TestBed.get(MyService); // this causes the error
        expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Any idea what might cause this problem and how to solve it?

I fail to see my problem, especially many tutorial out there do it exactly the same way.

Comment: Can't reproduce it https://plnkr.co/edit/G3ihIYvuQ8qFXpUlsBlw?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, as feared and expected at least after yurzuis comment: Everything was fine with the test itself.

But I have a mono repo with a scoped packages and the tests run from the main project (and not from the scoped packages itself) and unfortunately there were version mismatches between the angular packages which lead to those problems.

So I have to improve my testing setup to prevent this issues in the future.